# How to get a particular value in front of the filtered criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLGz0.png)[image]

I'm trying to insert a "Y" in every cell corresponding to a particular filtered year.
Eg: Filtered year - 2018, I'd need "Y" in all cells of column c.

However, if i include only 1 row of data(2018 in only cell b2), my macro keeps running and shows a run time error.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 3)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2018"

Set rng5 = Range("A3", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each cell In rng5
Range("c" & cell.Row).Value = "Y"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: As you are already performing the filter action in your code, you can just transpose all visible rows in column `C`. You don't need a loop to do this

Comment: Can you tell me how ? Kinda stuck with this one condition on my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF) 'Change

    'Set filter
    .Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 3)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2018"

    'Determine last row
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'For all visible (filtered) rows, value "Y" in col C
    If LRow = 3 Then
        .Range("C3").Value = "Y"
    Else        
        .Range("B3:B" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y"
    End If

End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Sub below will clear filters and correctly handle cases of filtered values in row 2, which can cause the error to occur

```
Sub Macro1()
With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF) 'Change

    'Clear filter
    If .AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter

    'Set filter
    .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2018"

    'Determine last row
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'For all visible (filtered) rows, value "Y" in col C
    If LRow > 2 Then
        If LRow = 3 Then
            .Range("C3").Value = "Y"
        Else
            .Range("B3:B" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y"
        End If
    End If

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim. The macro does filter & identify the last row, but not insert a "Y"

Comment: What is the reason for you wanting to populate from row 3 onwards, instead of row 2? I have added a workaround for when you encounter only one row.

Comment: Need to filter through the entire dataset multiple times based on "Year" and put a "Y" value in front of it. The year count however, is dynamic. So it'll keep on changing.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean with "the year count however, is dynamic". Do you mean that the number of rows in col `B` is subject to change? Seeing as how in your example you have one header row, you may as well place "Y" values in `C2`, but that is to your discretion. Have you tried the altered code?

Comment: Right! the rows in column B would keep changing. Tried the altered code, but it does not insert Y.

Comment: Then there's something in your workbook that is not showing in the example you provided. I have tested my code to be working on your example.

Comment: Added additional code to account for filtered values in row 2

Answer (score 0):

**`TagFilteredYear`** does what you want to do. **`TestMe`** is just to test **`TagFilteredYear`** UDF

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    TagFilteredYear "2018", "Y"

End Sub

Sub TagFilteredYear(ByVal sFilterCriteria As String, ByVal sSetValueTo As String)

    Dim iLRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Clear any existing autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter

        ' Get row count
        iLRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Filter range
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sFilterCriteria

        ' Populate visible cells in column C with specified value (starting form 2 row)
        .Range("C2:C" & iLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = sSetValueTo

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not address OP's problem as he wants to filter from row 3 onwards which throws a `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error`, which I did address in my code

Comment: @TimStack: OP never listed `Row 3` requirement in their initial post. If OP want's to add further requirements, they can start a new question. My answer meets the requirements of OP's original query

Comment: "If i include only 1 row of data (2018 in only cell b2), my macro keeps running and shows a run time error" and `Range("A3", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. This error will still occur in your code if you start from `C3` like OP does.

Comment: @TimStack: Have you tried my code? because I have and it doesn't throw any error for me even when there is a single cell value in `B2`

Comment: I have, with `.Range("C3:C" & iLRow).SpecialCells...` because of OP's code